# Scala - StdTokenParsers parse not exactly as expected

Tags: scala, parsing

I have an assignment to parse a demo language, this is the code that has problems in it, the other work as I expected:

```
  def parse(s: String) = phrase(program)(new lexical.Scanner(s))

  def program: Parser[Any] = rep(sttment)



  //Operator

  def expression: Parser[Any] = lv1 ~ rep(("<" | ">" | "<=" | ">=") ~ lv1)

  def lv1: Parser[Any] = lv2 ~ rep(("<>" | "==") ~ lit)

  def lv2: Parser[Any] = lit ~ opt("." ~ ident ~ opt("(" ~ repsep(expression, ",") ~ ")"))

  def lit: Parser[Any] = ident | boollit | floatlit | intlit | stringlit

  // Statements
  def sttment: Parser[Any] = sttm | "{" ~  rep(sttment) ~ "}"

  def sttm: Parser[Any] = (assignment ||| returnsttm ||| invokesttm ||| ifsttm ||| whilesttm |||
        repeatsttm ||| forsttm ||| breaksttm ||| continuesttm ) ~ ";"

  def assignment: Parser[Any] = lhs ~ ":=" ~ expression

  def lhs: Parser[Any] = ( "self" ~ "." ~ ident )|||( ident ~ "." ~ ident )|||( ident ~ "[" ~ expression ~ "]")|||ident

  def ifsttm: Parser[Any] = "if" ~ expression ~ "then" ~ sttment ~ opt("else" ~ sttment)

  def whilesttm: Parser[Any] = "while" ~ expression ~ "do" ~ sttment

  def repeatsttm: Parser[Any] = "repeat" ~ sttment ~ "until" ~ expression

  def forsttm: Parser[Any] = "for" ~ ident ~ ":=" ~ expression ~ ("to" | "downto") ~ expression ~ "do" ~ sttment

  def breaksttm: Parser[Any] = "break"

  def continuesttm: Parser[Any] = "continue"

  def returnsttm: Parser[Any] = "return" ~ expression

  def invokesttm: Parser[Any] = expression ~ "." ~ ident ~ "(" ~ repsep(expression, ",") ~ ")"

  def primtype: Parser[Any] = "integer" | "float" | "bool" | "string" | "void"


  def boollit: Parser[Any] = elem("boolean", _.isInstanceOf[lexical.BooleanLit])

  def floatlit: Parser[Any] = elem("real", _.isInstanceOf[lexical.FloatLit])

  def intlit: Parser[Any] = elem("integer", _.isInstanceOf[lexical.IntLit])

  def stringlit: Parser[Any] = elem("string", _.isInstanceOf[lexical.StringLit])
```

For example, when I parse this string:

```
io.writeFloatLn(s.getArea());
```

It return:

```
``.'' expected but `;' found"
```

at the "return 1".  Can someone tell me what mistakes did I make?

Edit:
- I am sorry, because I didn't understand my problem enough, I have asked it the wrong way, now I write the exact error it make.

- Delimiter and keywords list:

  reserved ++= List("bool", "break", "continue", "do", "downto", "else", "float", "for",
      "if", "integer", "new", "repeat", "string", "then", "to", "until", "while", "return",
      "true", "false", "void", "null", "self", "final", "class", "extends", "abstract")

  delimiters ++= List("[", "]", "(", ")", ":", ";", ".", ",", "{", "}", "+", "=",
      "-", "*", "/", "\", "%", ":=", "==", "<", "<=", ">", ">=", "<>", "&&", "!", "||", "^")

Comment: Why def sttment = sttm | "{" ~  rep(sttment) ~ "}" instead of sttment = sttm | ("{" ~  rep(sttment) ~ "}") ?

Comment: @dk14 Um, why the "?" ?

Comment: @dk14 Im sorry that I asked wrong, please review my question again.  Though I think that "|" has lower precedence so it is not neccessary to put in brackets.

Comment: please edit your question again - you didn't specified at which "." you've got an error

Comment: as i can see from grammar - there is no "." ~ "ident" inside brackets in invokesttm - so parser expecting just simple expression here.

Comment: @dk14 No, the parser say that instead of the ";" at the end I should have a "." and may be something after that which of course not what I want. About the "."~"ident" inside bracket, I think when it reached the ";", the part inside the brackets should have been parsed, right?

Comment: Seems that io.writeFloatLn(s.getArea()) is parsed as stringLit expression because you didn't added "(", ".", ")" as delimiters (override def delimiters = ...)

Comment: @dk14 Please view my delims and keywords in the question I just edited. I'm sure I have added those.

Comment: and still my answer is - there is no "." ~ "ident" inside brackets in invokesttm ! So parser expects expression here - and find something - maybe lv2 - you have complex logic here - anyway there should be invokesttm (or just sttm) inside brackets, like expression ~ "." ~ ident ~ "(" ~ repsep(somesttm, ",") ~ ")"

Comment: your expression not supporting statements inside - so s.getArea() is ineligible input for them

Comment: expression itself is an invokesttm, so your whole io.writeFloatLn(s.getArea()) parsed as expression - and then waiting for another . after

Comment: Because it can be: io.writeFloatLn(5); or io.writeFloatLn(s.getArea()*10+fs.getArea());, and real expressions is more than lv2 so I can not put sttm in place of expression, the program is expected to see the s.getArea() as expression (lv2), and io.writeFloatLn(...) as sttm, but somehow it didn't.

Comment: @dk14 Oh, you are right, how could I missed it! Do you know some workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like they work as expected - io.writeFloatLn(s.getArea()) was parsed as expression inside statement - so parser just waiting for "." from your statement, something like:

```
io.writeFloatLn(s.getArea()).writeFloatLn()
```

I think you can use brackets only as a part of statement (call operation) or only as a part of expression (application), depending on which language do you need - imperative or functional. Same for `.`.

Comment: You are right, so how do I get out of this? Invoke statement must start with a expression.

Comment: i edited answer. you can review your BNF grammar - brackets and . cannot be part of both expressions and statements - it's one of two: application operation or call operation - not both in one language.

Comment: Thank you, you mean like: "("~expression~")"~"."~ident... ?

Comment: i mean you can remove invocation (and may be improve your expressions). For example, Scala itself don't have invocations in AST - only Apply().

Answer (score 0):

I would have to see more of your code to be sure but I don't see `returnsttm` in your `sttm` list.  That would prevent `sttment` from matching `returnsttm` before looking for the opening brace.

Comment: The "returnsttm" is the second from bottom in the previous code, if it isn't there, I dont think my program will even compile, now it is the 7 from bottom. I have edited the code so it have a parsing start.

Comment: Can you review the question again? My previous question is all wrong.